# Filtering returned values variable with majority votes

Tags: python, object-detection

Good day, I am new to python and currently I am trying to work with my object detection assignment. What I am currently working with is to do filtering and do counting for objects that have been detected. For e.g , I have 3 return variables such as **boxes** (bounding boxes that appeared, to do counting), **classId** and **confidence** (to determine the object classes and its probability) with

```
print (len(boxes),classId,confidence)
```

and i got values like this (1 sec for 50+ values)

```
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.91407496)

(1, 'Sunbear', 0.93277943)

(1, 'Sunbear', 0.8578589)

(2, 'Sunbear', 0.29979056)

(1, 'Sunbear', 0.8787856)

(2, 'Sunbear', 0.32679325)

(1, 'Sunbear', 0.79356045)
```

**Here is what i wanted to do:**

To take the majority values that appeared for every 10 ( or more) returned values for boxes, classId and confidence (average value for this), to eliminate random fluctuation. Here are part of my codes,

```
        classIds = []
        confidences = []
        boxes = []
        for out in outs:
            for detection in out:
                scores = detection[5:]
                classId = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[classId]
                if confidence > confThreshold:
                    center_x = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
                    center_y = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)
                    width = int(detection[2] * frameWidth)
                    height = int(detection[3] * frameHeight)
                    left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                    top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                    classIds.append(classId)
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    boxes.append([left, top, width, height])
                    if classId ==0:
                        classId = 'Asian_elephant'
                    elif classId ==1:
                        classId = 'Sunbear'
                    elif classId ==2:
                        classId = 'Tapir'
                    #print ()
                    #logging.debug('%s %s %s', len(boxes), confidence,classId)
                    #logging.debug(boxes)
                    print ((len(boxes),classId,confidence))
```

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

If classId of 'Sunbear' appeared 5 times or more **continuously** , it will print the returned values and the count will reset back to 0 or else it will keep resetting to zero till the condition is met.

```
                    count=0
                    while classId=='Sunbear':  
                        count+=1
                        if count>=5:
                            print ((len(boxes),classId,confidence))
                            break
```

but somehow the returned values are the same in or outside the loop. Is this the right way of doing this, or there is some more efficient ways to do it. Please bear with me, I am new to programming, thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the result that you got?

Comment: @gameon67 something like this                                                                                            
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.91407496)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.91407496)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.93277943)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.93277943)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.8578589)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.8578589)
(2, 'Sunbear', 0.29979056)
(2, 'Sunbear', 0.29979056)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.8787856)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.8787856)
(2, 'Sunbear', 0.32679325)
(2, 'Sunbear', 0.32679325)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.79356045)
(1, 'Sunbear', 0.79356045)
 as you can see both inside and outside (loop) values are the same